# Just installed ubuntu gnome 3 15.04, on a new Yoga 3 14 but the hardware for the wifi is disabled and I can't turn it on with the wifi switch?

Tags: networking, wireless, 15.04, lenovo, wifi-hardware-switch

I have tried a few commands I found online and I also disabled and then re-enabled the wireless capabilities in the BIOS screen but still no Wifi. I cannot use an Ethernet cable because the Yoga 3 14 doesn't have a port for it. My computer is dual booted with Windows 10 and the Wifi works just fine when I use Windows 10. I have already tried installing Additional Drivers and updating it but it says there are no Additional Drivers for me to install and that everything is up to date.

Comment: Please try: `sudo modprobe -r ideapad-laptop` If your wireless switch works, I will then propose a permanent solution.

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked! I'd spent hours yesterday trying to enable the WiFi and your one command did it in less than 3 seconds!!!

Comment: So it works the but the Wifi returns to being disabled after I restart my computer. So I guess I will be needing that permanent solution.

Comment: Please edit to include results from `uname -a; sudo dmidecode | grep 'Product Version'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module `ideapad-laptop` is supposed to correctly translate key presses into action; in your case, enable and disable wireless. In several models, including the Yoga, it is faulty. You can blacklist the module until a fix is pushed out. In a terminal:

```
sudo -i
modprobe -r ideapad-laptop
echo "blacklist ideapad-laptop"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
exit
```

You should be all set.

Comment: If my answer has been helpful, please accept it: http://askubuntu.com/tour Glad it's working!